# virsh, how to list autostart domains?

Tags: kvm, libvirt, virsh

In `virsh` how do I see which domains are marked as autostart? `virsh list` does not show which domains are marked as autostart.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the man page:-

```
virsh list --autostart
```

should do it.

Comment: Running 'virsh list --help' on a CentOS install shows '--autostart' as an option.  The virsh installed is version 0.10.2 and it's the same version for libvirt.

Comment: Debian Wheezy is on 0.9.12 which may explain it.

Comment: Use `--all` to include stopped domains as well. E.g. `sudo virsh list --autostart --all`

Answer (score 19):

I realize this is a very old thread - on my RHEL6.5 system, this works, with the usual caveat that if you don't say `--all`, `virsh list` will only list info for running domains.

So try

```
virsh list --all --autostart
```

and/or

```
virsh list --all --no-autostart
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a universal script for getting autostart information. To list domains (VMs) that have autostart enable put in `virsh_autostart_info.sh` and run:
`virsh_autostart_info.sh | grep -i enabled`. You could of course clear it up to just display names or whatever you want.

```
##
# Configuration
#
VIRSH=/usr/bin/virsh

##
# Simple list of domains (VMs)
#
list_domains() {
    # list, skipping headers, capturing number and domName, and then strip Id and State column
    $VIRSH list --all | awk '$1 == "-" || $1+0 > 0 { print $2 }'
}

##
# Processing
#

## full info
#echo ""
#list_domains | while read vmName; do
#    $VIRSH dominfo $vmName
#done

# just autostart info
echo ""
list_domains | while read vmName; do
    autostartStatus=`$VIRSH dominfo $vmName | grep -i autostart`
    echo $vmName $autostartStatus
done
```

Comment: `virsh list --autostart` didn't work for me in centos 6.5

Comment: Thx for the script, it pointed me in the right direction. For anyone needeing a simple command here it is: `virsh dominfo $VM_NAME | grep -i autostart` will show `Autostart:      enable`; you can disable with `virsh autostart --disable $VM_NAME`, and now the output will be: `Autostart:      disable`